# Strictly conform UML modelling in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to configure Enterprise Architect (my version is 13) to allow only strictly conform UML modelling?

I have found some help page on [model Validation (in version 9.3)](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/testing/configuring_model_validation.htmlhttp://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/testing/configuring_model_validation.html), but cannot find the command `Project > Model Validation > Configure` in the ribbon interface.

An example of a non-conform UML model is IMHO the following:

[image: use case diagram]

Comment: @GeertBellekens I updated the picture

Comment: @GeertBellekens The validation (`Validate current package`) does not find any errors or warnings in the above model. Why?

Comment: Because it might not be perfect. What's allowed and what isn't is hard to decipher from the UML specs (you need to dig into all those OCLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Start button and enter `valid` in the search field. The 3rd entry is what you are looking for.

Usually this is turned on completely. There's also `Strict Connector Syntax` in the `Options/Links`.

Comment: All items in the list are active, but I where do I find `Strict Connector Syntax`?

Comment: The Validation (`Validate current package`) does not find any errors or warnings in the above model. Why?

Comment: As I said: Search `option` in  the start and choose `Preferences` then. It's also on per default. I'm not sure where an association between UCs is really invalid. That's a different question. I would not have issues with associated Actors, though.

Comment: I found the setting and it is active. I guess I have to reiterate over the UML spec to gain clarity.